# Sort list of Tuples by Secondary List, Skip Missing Values in Python

Tags: python

Trying to sort a list of tuples that are returned from a mysql cursor in python, by using a secondary list of values.

List used to order:

```
[126028, 255872, 252614, 370772, 460757, 2, 412173, 384558, 111669, 232514]
```

The list of tuples to sort:

```
[(111669, '4b2c702d01e33f4bf5a816877d186de9.jpg'), 
(126028, 'f34d5dcb7311320a81430076604286a5.jpg'), 
(232514, 'b53ba7b840ce4e9e39c67e1c55af56b1.jpg'), 
(255872, '06225265afb87e7147a611f3e7ec2c4c.jpg'), 
(370772, '50502846b5203bd75a17936962ff37ca.jpg'), 
(384558, '07f3ea5009dbe63bea5211b9c90144cb.jpg'), 
(412173, 'b1e23c2f41e24459c12f1e5299662534.jpg'), 
(460757, 'd1b6a265ac26c327684b562be69641f7.jpg')]
```

Ideally if elements aren't found in the returned results, they should be eliminated. Here's the new sorted order where you can see the values `[252614, 2]` were not found, therefore they would be excluded:

```
[(126028, 'f34d5dcb7311320a81430076604286a5.jpg'), 
(255872, '06225265afb87e7147a611f3e7ec2c4c.jpg'), 
(370772, '50502846b5203bd75a17936962ff37ca.jpg'), 
(460757, 'd1b6a265ac26c327684b562be69641f7.jpg'),
(412173, 'b1e23c2f41e24459c12f1e5299662534.jpg'), 
(384558, '07f3ea5009dbe63bea5211b9c90144cb.jpg'), 
(111669, '4b2c702d01e33f4bf5a816877d186de9.jpg'),
(232514, 'b53ba7b840ce4e9e39c67e1c55af56b1.jpg')]
```

Here is what I've tried:

```
btree_ids = [126028, 255872, 252614, 370772, 460757, 2, 412173, 384558, 111669, 232514]

media_id_list = [(111669, '4b2c702d01e33f4bf5a816877d186de9.jpg'), 
    (126028, 'f34d5dcb7311320a81430076604286a5.jpg'), 
    (232514, 'b53ba7b840ce4e9e39c67e1c55af56b1.jpg'), 
    (255872, '06225265afb87e7147a611f3e7ec2c4c.jpg'), 
    (370772, '50502846b5203bd75a17936962ff37ca.jpg'), 
    (384558, '07f3ea5009dbe63bea5211b9c90144cb.jpg'), 
    (412173, 'b1e23c2f41e24459c12f1e5299662534.jpg'), 
    (460757, 'd1b6a265ac26c327684b562be69641f7.jpg')]
print(sorted(media_id_list, key=lambda x: btree_ids.index(x[0])))
```

Comment: And your own attempt?

Comment: Added code @WillemVanOnsem

Comment: maybe create dictionary `d[126028] = f34d5dcb7311320a81430076604286a5.jpg` and then you can use first list to get elements in expected order.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

your approach seems to work (to some extent) but is very complex:

- using `sort` here is overkill and inefficient
- `index` performs a linear search so it's inefficient as well
- and yes, `index` fails with an exception if your sort list doesn't have all the values that your list of tuples have

My proposal: Just create a dictionary out of your input data.

Then build the list of tuples using a list comprehension, iterating on the sort list (that directly provides the order) & filtering out the items whose keys aren't in the sort list (that removes the items which aren't in the sort list):

```
data_in = [(111669, '4b2c702d01e33f4bf5a816877d186de9.jpg'),
(126028, 'f34d5dcb7311320a81430076604286a5.jpg'),
(232514, 'b53ba7b840ce4e9e39c67e1c55af56b1.jpg'),
(255872, '06225265afb87e7147a611f3e7ec2c4c.jpg'),
(370772, '50502846b5203bd75a17936962ff37ca.jpg'),
(384558, '07f3ea5009dbe63bea5211b9c90144cb.jpg'),
(412173, 'b1e23c2f41e24459c12f1e5299662534.jpg'),
(460757, 'd1b6a265ac26c327684b562be69641f7.jpg')]

sort_list = [126028, 255872, 252614, 370772, 460757, 2, 412173, 384558, 111669, 232514]

data_in = dict(data_in)

data_out = [(k,data_in[k]) for k in sort_list if k in data_in]

print(data_out)
```

results in:

```
[(126028, 'f34d5dcb7311320a81430076604286a5.jpg'), 
 (255872, '06225265afb87e7147a611f3e7ec2c4c.jpg'),
 (370772, '50502846b5203bd75a17936962ff37ca.jpg'),
 (460757, 'd1b6a265ac26c327684b562be69641f7.jpg'), 
 (412173, 'b1e23c2f41e24459c12f1e5299662534.jpg'),
 (384558, '07f3ea5009dbe63bea5211b9c90144cb.jpg'),
 (111669, '4b2c702d01e33f4bf5a816877d186de9.jpg'),
 (232514, 'b53ba7b840ce4e9e39c67e1c55af56b1.jpg')]
```

you can verify that removing values from `sort_list` issues a correct, yet smaller, result, as expected.

Comment: Perfect, thank you! I'm new to Python so I appreciate the additional input.

Answer (score 0):

If you are fine doing this with extra space, you can convert the tuple list to a dictionary, and then iterate through the order list, placing key/value pairs into an answer list.

```
tuple_list = dict(tuple_list)
answer = []

for key in order_list:    
    if key in tuple_list:
        answer.append(key, tuple_list[key])
```